# Hide/Show container panels in MVC using JQuery/Partial Views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

View:

1. When user selects an item from foreach loop the browse hides and selected container shows. When the user clicks the goback link it goes back to normal but after this it does not work with any other items in the list but only the first selected item.
2. I want to improve the above code to use partial views - pls can someone give me examples on how to do this using MVC 3 partial views or some code. thanks

Comment: Try a .on('click' instead of .click(

Comment: @subin that is no different.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Worth a try. "When the user clicks the go back link it goes back to normal but after this it does not work with any other items"

Comment: @Subin, both internally bind click event. There is no doubt

Comment: Subin your suggestion does NOT work, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you have lots of repeated `id` attributes in the loop. These need to be unique. Change them to `class` attributes and it should work:

```
<div id="panel2" class="span4">            
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            @foreach(x item in Model) {
                <tr class="tableBody">
                    <td><u><a class="data" href="#">@item.Name </a></u></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
$(".data").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#BrowseContainer').hide();
    $('#SelectedContainer').show();
    var txt = $(e.target).text();
    alert(txt);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/dWMu2/)

Comment: Thanks Rory, works brilliant. Can you please help me with the second question on using partial views for the above because otherwise I will endup with several containers and hide/show methods.

Comment: You don't state in what way you want to use partials to improve the code. You're probably best to open a new question for that as it's quite a broad topic. Make sure you state what you're trying to achieve with the partials.

Comment: @user2906420, accept this answer, if it works for the question. Please make use of SOF votes/acceptance